# How to create a border in css that doesn't change size?

Tags: html, css

So I have this code:

```
<h1 id="result" style="color:black; font-family: Bradley Hand; font-size:50px; position:absolute; top:17%; left:60%">
    text
</h1>
```

How can I make a border that if I put a longer text in, my border will keep its position and change its size, to make my text still in the border? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your question... Just adding the `border` property will achieve the behaviour you are explaining. Maybe you could try rephrasing the question if the current answers are not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `border: 1px solid black` (for example) to what you have works perfectly fine. The `h1` element will grow and shrink to fit it's content and the border will do so as well:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('result');
const sentence = "HELLO! IT LOOKS LIKE THIS IS WORKING FINE...";

let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  index = (index % sentence.length) + 1;

  result.innerHTML = sentence.slice(0, index);
}, 250);
```

```css
#result {
  position:absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  color: black;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Anyway, I suspect you may be referring to the border changing your element's dimension:

```css
#bar1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: red;
  margin: .25rem;
}

#bar2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: cyan;
  margin: .25rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar1"></div>
<div id="bar2"></div>
```

That's because by default, your element's `width` and `height` are actually a sum of the specified `width` and `height` properties, plus `padding` plus `border`, as you can see from the example above.

If that's the case, you have two options to keep the dimensions just as specified with `width` and `height`:

- Using [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp). That will make padding and border included in the element's total width and height.
- Using [`box-shadow`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp) instead of `border`. You can use the `inset` property to draw the shadow to the inside of the element instead of to the outside.

```css
#bar1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: red;
  margin: .25rem;
}

#bar2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: cyan;
  margin: .25rem;
  border: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bar3 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  margin: .25rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px black;
}

#bar4 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1rem;
  background: lime;
  margin: .25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar1"></div>
<div id="bar2"></div>
<div id="bar3"></div>
<div id="bar4"></div>
```

Note  the 4th bar, the one with the outer `box-shadow` looks bigger, but if you inspect it, its dimensions are exactly the same as those in the other 3 bars.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add `border: solid 1px black;` to the `style` attribute, like this?

`<h1 id="result" style="border: solid 1px black; color:black; font-family: Bradley Hand; font-size:50px; position:absolute; top:17%; left:60%">text</h1>`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/LL57yd8j/

Here's some reading on CSS borders: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: good, but I meant that the border size stay in defalut. But the border will make the text size smaller if the text is longer. That is what I confuse.